# OOM exception while loading large bitmaps in android

Tags: android

I tried to display large Bitmaps in the application,I continuesly getting OOM exception,

Here is the Imageloader class I used

```
 public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    }

//    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url,ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

//        Bitmap bitmap=createScaledBitmap(memoryCache.get(url), 100,100,0);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
      //  Bitmap bitmaps=bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 0, 100, 100);

        if(bitmap!=null)
        {
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));

            System.gc();
//            bitmap.recycle();
//            bitmap=null;
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap( bitmap, 10,70,70));
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//            Log.v("first", "first");
        }
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
//            Log.v("second", "second");

        }    
    }

    private Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int i, int j, int k) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

   public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }//Lalit



    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=Wall.width;
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE1=Wall.height;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    } 






    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if(tag!=null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));

        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels,int width,int height) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

And my Memorycache class

```
public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private long size=0;//current allocated size
    private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

    public MemoryCache(){
        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){
        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            return cache.get(id);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat Output ------------>

```
01-09 12:40:38.940: E/dalvikvm-heap(18736): 1123536-byte external allocation too large for this process.
    01-09 12:40:38.979: D/GraphicsJNI(18736): Waiting for heap walker to free more memory
    01-09 12:40:38.979: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 4297K/8967K, external 22504K/23758K, paused 29ms
    01-09 12:40:38.979: D/GraphicsJNI(18736): Heap walker done, retry to allocate
    01-09 12:40:39.002: I/MemoryCache(18736): cache size=5691144 length=7
    01-09 12:40:39.112: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 89K, 53% free 4272K/8967K, external 21905K/22856K, paused 42ms
    01-09 12:40:39.127: E/dalvikvm-heap(18736): 2457600-byte external allocation too large for this process.
    01-09 12:40:39.167: D/GraphicsJNI(18736): Waiting for heap walker to free more memory
    01-09 12:40:39.167: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 4272K/8967K, external 21905K/22856K, paused 28ms
    01-09 12:40:39.167: D/GraphicsJNI(18736): Heap walker done, retry to allocate
    01-09 12:40:39.206: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 53% free 4270K/8967K, external 20808K/22856K, paused 38ms
    01-09 12:40:39.252: I/MemoryCache(18736): cache size=8148744 length=8
    01-09 12:40:39.323: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 148K, 53% free 4253K/8967K, external 23218K/25256K, paused 42ms
    01-09 12:40:39.331: E/dalvikvm-heap(18736): 960000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
    01-09 12:40:39.370: D/GraphicsJNI(18736): Waiting for heap walker to free more memory
    01-09 12:40:39.370: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 4253K/8967K, external 23218K/25256K, paused 28ms
    01-09 12:40:39.377: D/GraphicsJNI(18736): Heap walker done, retry to allocate
    01-09 12:40:39.409: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 53% free 4251K/8967K, external 23208K/25256K, paused 38ms
    01-09 12:40:39.424: E/dalvikvm-heap(18736): 960000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
    01-09 12:40:39.463: E/GraphicsJNI(18736): VM won't let us allocate 960000 bytes
    01-09 12:40:39.463: D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 4251K/8967K, external 23208K/25256K, paused 28ms
    01-09 12:40:39.463: D/skia(18736): --- decoder->decode returned false
    01-09 12:40:39.463: W/dalvikvm(18736): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
    01-09 12:40:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(18736): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-26
    01-09 12:40:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(18736): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    01-09 12:40:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    01-09 12:40:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
    01-09 12:40:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at com.beerbro.utils.ImageLoader.decodeFile(ImageLoader.java:190)
    01-09 12:40:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at com.beerbro.utils.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:100)
    01-09 12:40:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at com.beerbro.utils.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:257)
    01-09 12:40:39.471: W/ActivityManager(1320):   Force finishing activity com.stellent.beerbro/.Wall
```

I am loading the data from the Facebook graph api,I am getting Firstpage data and I am displaying the whole data at a time.I think this is making the memory to increase a lot.
So, how to handle that large amount of data.
please help

Answer (score 0):

You should use [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) to decode the bitmap' size without loading it into memory. ATM, if you try to load a large bitmap, you create it before checking if it it within the size range of the cache.

You should not force the GC, especially as it is run asynchronously and the system.gc forces it to be synchronous. The Bitmaps are not loaded on the java heap directly so anything that comes out of the cache should be recycled. Finally don't keep references to the bitmap.

Overall, I would use [LRUCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html) rather then your own cache.

Finally, being bias, I would suggest the likes of [enter link description here](http://androidimageloader.com/) which caches the images to disk and uses LRUCache for performances.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to use that LruCache,and I think there will be Helper classes like Memorycache,ImageLoader,where can I find those classes.